# 7z command line add file to a flat directory 7z file

Tags: python, 7z

I would like to compress file "./data/x.txt" to path "./data/x.7z".

When running

```
7z a ./data/x.txt.7z ./data/x.txt
```

The file "./data/x.txt" holds

```
data/x.txt
```

as opposed to just (what I want)

```
x.txt
```

However, I would like 7z to ignore the path "./data" directory inside of the x.7z file.  To clarify, I would like 7z to flatten the directory structure in the 7z file when adding x.txt.

Is this possible?

Comment: The case that the answers does not cover is `7z a test.7z certs/file1.crt keys/file1.key` (with a password, using 7z for its AES encryption which unlike zip, work everywhere it can be opened)

Answer (score 1):

One of possible solutions is to chdir to some directory before compressing.
For example:

```
$ cd data; 7z a ../test.7z *
$ 7z l ../test.7z
...

   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2011-02-18 15:29:53 ....A            6           11  x.txt
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
...
```

Yet another way is using another archiver, e.g. `rar`. It has a lot of useful command line swithes. Your problem can be solved with `-ep/-ep1` options:

```
$ rar a -ep test.rar data
```

or

```
$ rar a -ep1 test.rar data
```

The piece of `rar` help:

```
  ep            Exclude paths from names
  ep1           Exclude base directory from names
```

Comment: Thank you for the alternatives.  I am running 7z through subprocess in python, so I am wary of changing directory.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out an alternative that works for me.  I am utilizing [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) to call 7z. The cwd attribute changes the working directory for the subprocess command. The code below solves my example above, where 'data' is the path that I would like to add a file from.

```
args = [
        '7z',
        'a',
        filename_7z,
        filename,
        ]
output = subprocess.check_output(args, cwd = 'data').decode("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

what dr01 answered is generally correct, but why use 7z for compressing a single file at all?

I'd suggest you take a look at [`xz`](http://tukaani.org/xz/) or maybe even [`pxz`](http://jnovy.fedorapeople.org/pxz/pxz.html), if that's available on your distro.
`xz` works well with `tar`, newer versions of tar have the "-J" switch, which runs it through `xz`

In any event, you can use `xz` to compress a single file, just as you'd use `gzip` or `bzip2`:

```
$ xz file.txt
```

*(creates file `file.txt.xz`)*

Comment: Is xz or pxz compatible with 7zip?  My target audience is windows users and I hope to achieve compatibility with decent compression.

Comment: That depends on the archiving program that the user uses. In case you want to distribute files, that are for users that potentially don't have any archiving programs, I'd consider using SFX. `7z` can do that. `xz` uses the same compression algorithm, things like peazip can handle `.xz` files.

Comment: xz also lacks other option that the example might omit, like encryption

Comment: @GertvandenBerg that is correct, it *purely* does compression. If encryption is desired something like `gpg` or `ccrypt` should be used. However, this goes beyond the scope of the original question which asked for simple compression of just one file.

Comment: @polemon Questions with suck parameters would likely be marked as duplicates of this one though....